# OSError with pandas.read_csv(): Initializing from file failed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import, filepath

I have a problem while trying to read measurement data from `.txt` files in `csv` format with `pandas.read_csv()`. My Code works fine except that it fails with an error when I try to assemble the file path in a for loop:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

root_folder = 'C:\\some\\root\\folder'
filename = 'Log_data.txt'

def get_data(root_folder, filename):   
    df_list = []
    for folder in os.listdir(root_folder + '\\' + 'measurements'):
        df = pd.read_csv(root_folder + '\\measurements\\' + folder + '\\' + 
                                             filename, 
                                             sep=' ',
                                             names= ['Date','Time','Rx power','Rx snr',
                                                     'BNO Az','HMC Az','Ref Az','Now Az',
                                                     'CONTR TGT Az','YUN TGT Az',
                                                     'Ref TGT Az','TGT Az','BNO El',
                                                     'HMC El','Ref El','Now El',
                                                     'CONTR TGT El','YUN TGT El',
                                                     'Ref TGT El','TGT El','Ref Lat',
                                                     'YUN Lat','Now Lat','Ref Lon',
                                                     'YUN Lon','Now Lon','YUN Flag Az',
                                                     'YUN Flag El','YUN Modus',
                                                     'Ref HDG dGPS','Ref HDG Trailer'])
        df['File'] = folder[9:] 
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
        df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
        df['Time'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'][0]
        df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.total_seconds()
        df = df.set_index([df.index, 'File', 'Date', 'Time'], drop = True)
    df_list.append(df)        
    df_big = pd.concat(df_list)
    return df_big

df = get_data(root_folder, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error source/solution. The problem was with german umlauts in my folder names. I had to make sure to use the proper encoding for read_csv().

```
df = pd.read_csv(root_folder + '\\Messdaten\\' + folder + '\\' + filename, 
encoding='iso-8859-1', ....
```